# SSL changes in android kitkat keeping connection from working?

Tags: android, ssl, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

Have there been any changes to the android SSL settings in kitkat? 
We have an App (phonegap, angularjs and jquery mobile) that worked fine with all previous android versions but now in 4.4 we get an SSL error.

```
12-23 19:25:24.915: WARN/chromium(18378): [WARNING:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(182)] Unmapped error reason: 1000
12-23 19:25:24.915: ERROR/chromium(18378): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(870)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -2
```

I used the webkit debug mode and sent XMLhttpRequests to different servers. https://www.google.de works fine, but our server doesn't only with http.

So here are some details to our (customers) certificate:
SSL3.0  with RC4_128. Auth is SHA1 & RSA. It doesn't support TLS-Renegotiation.

I found this: https://code.google.com/p/k9mail/issues/detail?id=6046

Dont know if it is relevant.

My assumption: Android kitkat doesnt support ssl 3.0 anymore and requires TLS 1.x

But i have no way of knowing for sure and i dont want to tell the customer to change their certificate and then it doesnt work because in the end it was still our fault.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `WebView`, which powers Cordova/PhoneGap, switched in Android 4.4 to use Chromium instead of a separate WebKit implementation. I would not surprise me if SSL behavior changes occurred as a result of it.

Comment: yes i am aware of the change this is how we were able to debug into the webapp. however i cannot find any ressources showing which forms of ssl are ok for chromium 30 or which are rejected

Comment: Is there any ressource that shows which ssl technologies are accepted by chromium on mobile devices or am i out of luck? :(

Comment: @pyus13 I have to admit it has been too long to remember, why are you having the same troubles?

Comment: I am getting the same error in Android 4.4.2 devices .

Comment: did you check your certificate? maybe its also a ssl3.0 connection and should be tls

Comment: ya i think so, any solution for the same except changing the client certificate which is actually not possible .